# Exporting Nodal Surfaces/Minimal Surfaces as any 3D source (obj,stl,mb....)

Tags: list-manipulation

I have been trying to export the surfaces that I gathered in the Wolfram Mathematica application,[image: This is the equation that I am playing with]

So is there any way to export surface this to Maya,Cinema 4D, Rhino , or any 3D environment for 3D printing and maybe to optimise it a bit more further.

If you could help me I would really appreciate it,

This is the code , but I find it from the descriptions of the Nodal Surface,
(https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/NodalSurfacesOfDegenerateStates/ ),

I want to export this surface to any 3D platform, so I typed ''Export["DynamicModule.stl", output]'' but I cannot export it as a STL or OBJ .

```
    Manipulate[ Module[{\[CurlyEpsilon] = 10^-6, c1 = Tan[a1], c2 = Tan[a2], 
   c3 = Tan[a3], c4 = Tan[a4], c5 = Tan[a5], c6 = Tan[a6]}, 
  ContourPlot3D[
   Evaluate[
    c6 Sin[3 x] Sin[2 y] Sin[z] + c4 Sin[2 x] Sin[3 y] Sin[z] + 
      c5 Sin[3 x] Sin[y] Sin[2 z] + c2 Sin[x] Sin[3 y] Sin[2 z] + 
      c3 Sin[2 x] Sin[y] Sin[3 z] + c1 Sin[x] Sin[2 y] Sin[3 z] == 
     0], {x, \[CurlyEpsilon], 
    Pi - \[CurlyEpsilon]}, {y, \[CurlyEpsilon], 
    Pi - \[CurlyEpsilon]}, {z, \[CurlyEpsilon], Pi - \[CurlyEpsilon]},
    Mesh -> False, ImageSize -> {400, 400}, Boxed -> False, 
   Axes -> False, NormalsFunction -> "Average", 
   PlotPoints -> ControlActive[10, 30], PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]],
 {{a1, 1, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Alpha]\), \(1\)]\)"}, -Pi/2 - 0.01, 
  Pi/2 + 0.01, ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{a2, 1, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Alpha]\), \(2\)]\)"}, -Pi/2 - 0.01, 
  Pi/2 + 0.01, ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{a3, 1, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Alpha]\), \(3\)]\)"}, -Pi/2 - 0.01, 
  Pi/2 + 0.01, ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{a4, 1, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Alpha]\), \(4\)]\)"}, -Pi/2 - 0.01, 
  Pi/2 + 0.01, ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{a5, 1, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Alpha]\), \(5\)]\)"}, -Pi/2 - 0.01, 
  Pi/2 + 0.01, ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{a6, 1, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Alpha]\), \(6\)]\)"}, -Pi/2 - 0.01, 
  Pi/2 + 0.01, ImageSize -> Tiny}, AutorunSequencing -> {1, 3, 5}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Left]


DynamicModule[{a1 = 1, a2 = 1, a3 = 1, a4 = 1, a5 = 1, a6 = 1}, 
 Module[{\[CurlyEpsilon] = 1/10^6, c1 = Tan[a1], c2 = Tan[a2], 
   c3 = Tan[a3], c4 = Tan[a4], c5 = Tan[a5], c6 = Tan[a6]}, 
  ContourPlot3D[
   Evaluate[((c6 Sin[3 x]) Sin[2 y]) Sin[
        z] + ((c4 Sin[2 x]) Sin[3 y]) Sin[
        z] + ((c5 Sin[3 x]) Sin[y]) Sin[
        2 z] + ((c2 Sin[x]) Sin[3 y]) Sin[
        2 z] + ((c3 Sin[2 x]) Sin[y]) Sin[
        3 z] + ((c1 Sin[x]) Sin[2 y]) Sin[3 z] == 
     0], {x, \[CurlyEpsilon], \[Pi] - \[CurlyEpsilon]}, {y, \
\[CurlyEpsilon], \[Pi] - \[CurlyEpsilon]}, {z, \[CurlyEpsilon], \[Pi] \
- \[CurlyEpsilon]}, Mesh -> False, ImageSize -> {400, 400}, 
   Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, NormalsFunction -> "Average", 
   PlotPoints -> ControlActive[10, 30], PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]]]

Export["DynamicModule.stl", output]
```

Comment: It's hard to read your screenshot, the text is very small - please post code we can copy/paste, not screenshots. You should really have posted the error you were getting too.  You are trying to export an undefined symbol called "output". You need to assign your plot to "output".

Comment: Also you can print and refine meshes from _Mathematica_ too, have a look at `FindMeshDefects`, `RepairMesh`, and `Printout3D`, however you will need to get the mesh from your `ContourPlot3D` first. You can do that by using `DiscretizeGraphics` on the plot.

Comment: I will say again, you have not assigned **output** to anything. You need to assign `output = ContourPlot3D[......]`

Comment: @flinty How do I print or refine meshes in Mathematica ? I understand this commands but I have problem with using them :(

Comment: If you have the plot in `output` then do `mesh=DiscretizeGraphics[output]`, then you can use `FindMeshDefects[mesh]`, `RepairMesh[mesh]`, and `Printout3D[mesh]` on the mesh.

Comment: Also, because of the `DynamicModule` and `Module`, the output you're exporting will always take the initial values of a1,a2,a3... etc.

Comment: I am literally lost , so in the first step what should I do can you please explain a bit slower I have not much experience with coding :( , so when you said that I am not assigning an output , what should I type for it so that I have an output.

Comment: *output* is highlighted in blue isn't it? It's just a symbol. You need to set it (assign something) or _Mathematica_ will not know what *output* means.

Comment: @flinty  So how can I output this as a mesh for example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set up your a1...a6 however you want them in a `Manipulate` as below. Note how `output` is set to the result of the `ContourPlot3D`:

```
Manipulate[
 With[{ε=10^-6, c1=Tan[a1], c2=Tan[a2], c3=Tan[a3], c4=Tan[a4], c5=Tan[a5], c6=Tan[a6]}, 
    output = ContourPlot3D[
    Evaluate[((c6 Sin[3 x]) Sin[2 y]) Sin[z] 
     + ((c4 Sin[2 x]) Sin[3 y]) Sin[z] 
     + ((c5 Sin[3 x]) Sin[y]) Sin[2 z] 
     + ((c2 Sin[x]) Sin[3 y]) Sin[2 z] 
     + ((c3 Sin[2 x]) Sin[y]) Sin[3 z] 
     + ((c1 Sin[x]) Sin[2 y]) Sin[3 z] == 0],
     {x, ε, π - ε}, {y, ε, π - ε}, {z, ε, π - ε}, Mesh -> False, ImageSize -> {400, 400}, 
     Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, NormalsFunction -> "Average", 
     PlotPoints -> ControlActive[10, 30], PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
    ],
    {{a1, 1}, -Pi, Pi},
    {{a2, 1}, -Pi, Pi},
    {{a3, 1}, -Pi, Pi},
    {{a4, 1}, -Pi, Pi},
    {{a5, 1}, -Pi, Pi},
    {{a6, 1}, -Pi, Pi}
 ]
```

Then in a separate cell, evaluate

```
mesh = DiscretizeGraphics[output]; Export["mesh.stl", mesh];
```

Comment: Thank you so much, can I use this export style for exporting my mesh as an obj as well ? Because when I tried my wolfram just crashes.

Comment: Yes, just change "mesh.stl" to "mesh.obj" - I don't know why it's crashing for you. Are you on v11 or v12 ? I'm on v12.1.1